# a collection of type `str` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=char>`

Tags: rust

The following code fails to compile

```
fn main() {
    let n = 10;
    let mut s = String::new();
    let v = vec!['a'; n];
    s += &v.into_iter().collect();
}
```

with the error:

```
error[E0277]: a collection of type `str` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `char`
 --> src/main.rs:5:25
  |
5 |     s += &v.into_iter().collect();
  |                         ^^^^^^^ a collection of type `str` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=char>`
  |
  = help: the trait `std::iter::FromIterator<char>` is not implemented for `str`
```

However this modification seems to work:

```
fn main() {
    let n = 10;
    let mut s = String::new();
    let v = vec!['a'; n];
    let t: String = v.into_iter().collect();
    s += &t;
}
```

I am trying to understand the reason. Any hints/explanation would help. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, you can use `String::extend` instead: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Extend.html - for example, `s.extend(v.into_iter());` or even `s.extend(v)`, since `extend` accepts `IntoIterator`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, what works:

```rust
fn main() {
    let n = 10;
    let mut s = String::new();
    let v = vec!['a'; n];
    s += &v.into_iter().collect::<String>();
}
```

Secondly, let's explore why that works. You can do add-assign `+=` on `String` because it implements [`AddAssign` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-AddAssign%3C%26%27_%20str%3E):

```
impl<'_> AddAssign<&'_ str> for String
```

but only if the right-hand-side is a `&str`. So in your first example, `rustc` tries to collect a vector of `char` into `str`. It won't work because the signature of [`Iterator::collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect):

```
fn collect<B>(self) -> B
where
    B: FromIterator<Self::Item>,
```

dictates that an iterator can only be collected into a container which implements [`FromIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html). Among all types that do [implement it](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html#implementors), you can see `str` is not one of them, but `String` is. That's the error message you've witnessed.

On the other hand, in your second example and the code in this answer, `rustc` is specifically told to collect into a `String`. And since `String` implements [`Deref` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-Deref) with `str` as the target type:

```
impl Deref for String {
    type target = str;
}
```

a `&String` can be coerced to `&str`. The compiler is now happy.

---

So now you should be able to decipher why the following funny looking code also works:

```
fn main() {
    use std::borrow::Cow;

    let n = 10;
    let mut s = String::new();
    let v = vec!['a'; n];
    s += &v.into_iter().collect::<Cow<'_, str>>();
}
```

Comment: It is the [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) trait that allows coercion from `&String` to `&str`. `AsRef`, on the other hand, is just a conversion trait (like `From`/`Into`) and has no special behavior in the language itself.

Comment: Depending on the OP's prior knowledge, it might make sense to mention _why_  `&str` doesn't make sense as the target of `collect`, i.e. why it doesn't and can't implement `FromIterator`. (E.g. because `collect` must return a container, and `&str` isn't one, but `String` is.)